# grunt watch compiled less but not generating css

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less

Grunt watch compiled my LESS file, but is not generating a CSS file. I don't know what the issue is. Can anyone out there help?

Here is my grunt code:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.initConfig({ 
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), 
    less: {
        options: {
            paths: 'less',
            yuicompress: true
        },
        files: {
            'styles.css': 'less/button.less'
        }
    },

    watch: {
        less: {
            files: 'less/*.less',
            tasks: 'less'
        }
    }
});
}
```

And here is my `package.json` code:

```json
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Awesome project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

See my folder structure below:

[image]

Grunt Watch working fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grunt expects your `less` task configuration to have one or more _targets. Each target, which can be arbitrarily named, would have a `files` object.

In *your* configuration, Grunt thinks that `files` is the *target*, hence why the console output shows `Running less:files`. When Grunt does not find a `files` object within the `files` target, it moves on.

In order to fix your configuration, you must add a target object that will wrap the `files` object. For example,

```js
less: {
    options: {
        paths: 'less',
        yuicompress: true
    },
    dev: {
        files: {
            'styles.css': 'less/button.less'
        }
    }
},
```

For more on Grunt task configuration and targets, see the [documentation](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets).